# Grafana Bigquery query to handle multiple value variable with All option enabled

Tags: google-bigquery, grafana, grafana-variable

I have created a Grafana dashboard with filter variables enabled along with "All" option enabled. I am working on BigQuery sql query to fetch the data.

I have constructed below query to fetch the data when "All" option is selected.

`SELECT count(*) AS FAILED_COUNT FROM BG_TABLE where COLUMN1 like '%'.`

with the above query I am able to fetch the data when user selects "All" option from dropdown but it fails when user selects multiple options from dropdown as the query is constructed like below

`SELECT count(*) AS FAILED_COUNT FROM BG_TABLE where COLUMN1 like 'COLUMN_VALUE_1','COLUMN_VALUE_2'.`

So to handle multiple options, I have updated query with "in" operator as below

`SELECT count(*) AS FAILED_COUNT FROM BG_TABLE where COLUMN1 in ('COLUMN_VALUE_1','COLUMN_VALUE_2')`

This resolved the problem with multiple options but failed when I select "All" option as the query is constructed like below

`SELECT count(*) AS FAILED_COUNT FROM BG_TABLE where COLUMN1 in ('%')`

Can someone help me with the query to handle both "All" and multiple options selection.

Comment: Did you set the `Custom all value` of the variable to `%` or why is it interpolated like that?

Comment: I saw somewhere in Google to pass % to fetch all records using Like operator, I have removed it and set to default blank and update variable query with not null condition and the issue got resolved

Answer (score 0):

Set the Custom All value default to blank and in variable query include NOT NULL condition like below

```
Select Name from employee where Name IS NOT NULL.
```